# What version of Visual Basic is my project using?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've inherited a .NET 4.61 Visual Basic project.  How do I see what version of the language the project is using?

In looked around Project Properties and didn't see anything obvious.  I am using Visual Studio 2022 with the project.

Comment: The last formal language version was 14, released with VS2015.  Nevertheless, they do maintain the language to keep compatible with changes in C# and .NET Core.  Those changes have the VS version number in which they were released.  For VS2022 you get 15.5 in a project that targets the legacy .NET Framework, 16.9 when you target .NET Core (aka .NET5+)

Comment: My own interest I guess, but why would it even matter what version of the language the project is using?  Doesn't what is or isn't available/supported really version of .net your targeting?

Comment: The version of the Language is usually set as `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` (same as `default`) in a Project, which depends on the version of Visual Studio; see [What's new for Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/whats-new/) and of course `vbc.exe`. Locate `vbc.exe` and run it with the `-langversion:?` switch: it shows which are the supported versions and which is the `latest` for that version of vbc.exe - See also [Select the Visual Basic language version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/configure-language-version)

Comment: *which is the `latest` for that version of vbc.exe* means that you may have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed (hence multiple versions of vbc.exe) and the *latest* version depends on which version of VS you're using to load a Project. Of course you can use `<LangVersion>` to set a specific version of the Language

Comment: @Jimi The `<LangVersion>` node is not in the project file.  I did run `vbc.exe -langversion:?` and it reported the [following](https://i.imgur.com/gNYnUrc.png).

Comment: That's the standard response for vbc.exe shipped with Visual Studio 2022. If you want to control the language version, add, e.g., `<LangVersion>16.9</LangVersion>` to the main PropertyGroup (the one that contains `<AssemblyName>`), open the Project and rebuild the Solution (try to write, e.g., `<LangVersion>18.9</LangVersion>` instead, see what happens when you rebuild the Solution) -- As mentioned, if you don't specify a `<LangVersion>`, it's defined as the `latest` for the current development platform

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 supports NET Framework versions 4.8

Visual Studio 2017 supports NET Framework versions 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, and 3.5

I recommend that you install Visual Studio 2017 for your project.

Comment: Or upgrade to 4.8

Comment: The question is about the version of the language, not the framework.